# Where or where from?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-patterns

I was wondering where you bought that book (from)? Is 'from' necessary in this sentence ?

Comment: My first thought was that it isn't necessary (thinking of buying a book in a shop). Then I realised that, with mail order or internet shopping, you do send for goods _from_ somewhere without having to go in person.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146950/where-did-you-buy-it-or-where-did-you-buy-it-from